# Packaging Python script for use by other users

Tags: python, macos

I've developed a script on windows and would like to make it available to other users. For windows users I've turned into an executable, but am wondering the best way to make available for mac os users. If I put all the modules (e.g. pandas, tkcalendar) and my script in one folder, send to the user, and have them install Python, will they be able to run the script, or will they need to pip install the modules from their own computer?

Comment: They have to do `pip install ...` for all the external packages that you have used until unless you create a wheel file out of it. Try to follow the instructions mentioned [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) so as to create a wheel file. As soon as you share the created wheel file with you they just need to do `pip install <path-to-wheel-file>`.

Comment: @lokesh I'm having trouble with this. When I go to generate the distribution archives, nothing happens. Are `__init__.py` and `setup.py` python files or text files? If python files, is it okay to create them in the file with my python script? Here's what I've done so far: Create a main file on my desktop titled `autodd`. Within `autodd` are the folders titled `nav` and `tests`. In SublimeText, I created the files `__init__`, `LICENSE`, and `README`. I moved `__init__` to the `nav` folder.

Comment: `__init__.py` and `setup.py` are python files. It should be created separately.` __init__.py` is a file that tells Python to treat the directory as a module. Your code and setup.py file code shouldn't be in the same file, there should be two files one for your code another for you setup code.